# What permissions are required to access SPSite.Usage?

Tags: 2010, permissions, object-model

I am using the `SPSite.Usage` property in the object model to get statistics on the size of a site collection in SharePoint 2010. With my own user account being a farm administrator, site collection administrator, database administrator and, indeed, a domain administrator, I can always retrieve this property. However, most normal users (including those with contributor permissions on the site in question) cannot access this property.

What are the minimum permissions required to access the `SPSite.Usage` property?

Answer (score 2):

There are site permission called *View Usage Data*. In default permission level, its only included in *full control* permission. However, You can change which permissions are included in a particular permission level (except for the Limited Access and Full Control permission levels), or you can create a new permission level to contain specific permissions

For more information, visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx

Comment: Although called _View Usage Data_ in the documentation, the actual permission is called _View Web Analytics Data_. Unfortunately, turning this on does not give the user permission to the `SPSite.Usage` property via the object model. It seems to be concerned more with usage reports than the raw data.

Comment: @BradleySmith is correct.  View Usage Data does not give an account permissions to use SPSite.   Anyone found a correct answer to the OP question?